# Fastest way to filter two lists based on a common field datapoint in 1-many configuration

Tags: c#, linq, list, join

This one is all about `performance`. I have two major `lists of objects` (here, I'll use `PEOPLE/PERSON` as the stand-in). First, I need to `filter one list` by the `First_Name property` - then I need to create `two filtered lists from each master list based on shared date` - one list with only one name, the other list with every name, but with both lists only containing matching date entries (no date in one list that doesn't exist in the other). I've written a `pseudo-code` to simplify the issue to the core question below. Please understand while reading that BIRTHDAY wasn't the best choice, as there are multiple date entries per person. So please pretend that each person has about 5,000 "birthdays" when reading the code below:

```
public class Person
{
    public string first_Name;
    public string last_Name;
    public DateTime birthday;
}
public class filter_People
{
    List<Person> Group_1 = new List<Person>();// filled from DB Table "1982 Graduates" Group_1 contains all names and all dates
    List<Person> Group_2 = new List<Person>();// filled from DB Table "1983 Graduates" Group_2 contains all names and all dates
    public void filter(List<Person> group_One, List<Person> group_Two)
    {
        Group_1 = group_One;
        Group_2 = group_Two;
        //create a list of distinct first names from Group_1
        List<string> distinct_Group_1_Name = Group_1.Select(p => p.first_Name).Distinct().ToList();

        //Compare each first name in Group_1 to EVERY first name in Group 2, using only records with matching birthdays
        Parallel.For(0, distinct_Group_1_Name.Count, dI => {
            //Step 1 - create a list of person out of group_1 that match the first name being iterated
            List<Person> first_Name_List_1 = Group_1.Where(m => m.first_Name == distinct_Group_1_Name[dI]).ToList();
            //first_Name_List_1 now contains a list of everyone named X (Tom). We need to find people from group 2 who match Tom's birthday - regardless of name

            //step 2 - find matching birthdays by JOINing the filtered name list against Group_2  
            DateTime[] merged_Dates = first_Name_List_1.Join(Group_2, d => d.birthday, b => b.birthday, (d, b) => b.birthday).ToArray();
            //Step 3 - create filtered lists where Filtered_Group_1 contains ONLY people named Tom, and Filtered_Group_2 contains people with ANY name sharing Tom's birthday. No duplicates, no missing dates.
            List<Person> Filtered_Group_1 = first_Name_List_1.Where(p => p.birthday.In(merged_Dates)).ToList();
            List<Person> Filtered_Group_2 = Group_2.Where(p => p.birthday.In(merged_Dates)).ToList();
            //Step 4 -- move on adn process the two filtered lists (outside scope of question)
            //each name in Group_1 will then be compared to EVERY name in Group_2 sharing the same birthday
            //compare_Groups(Filtered_Group_1,Filtered_Group_2)

        });
    }
}
public static class Extension
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
    {
        return list.Contains(source);
    }
}
```

Here, the idea is to take `two different master name lists` from the DB and create sub-lists where dates match (one with only one name, and the other with all names) allowing for a `one-to-many comparison` based on `datasets` of the same length with matching date indices. Originally, the idea was to simply load the lists from the DB, but the lists are long and loading all name data and using `SELECT/WHERE/JOIN` is much faster. I say "much faster" but that's relative.

I've tried converting `Group_1` and `Group_2` to Dictionaries and matching dates by using keys. Not much improvement. `Group_1 has about 12Million records` (`about 4800 distinct names` with multiple dates each), and Group_2 has about the same, so the input here is `12Million` records and the output is a bazillion records. Even though I'm running this method as a separate Task and queuing the results for another thread to process, it's taking forever to split these lists and keep up.

Also, I realize this code doesn't make much sense using class Person, but it's only a representative of the problem essentially using pseudocode. In reality, this method sorts multiple datasets on date and compares one to many for correlation.

Any help on how to accomplish filtering this one to many comparison in a more productive way would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The ultimate goal here is to get two lists (or arrays); list_1 would consist of 4000 entries, all with the first name TOM and with 4000 different dates, and list_2 would contain 400 names, each with the same 4000 dates such that for every name in List_2, List_2.Where(p=>p.first_Name == List_1.first_Name).ToArray()[15] would produce the same date at List_1[15].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in the current format, I see way too many issues for it to become performance oriented with the kind of data you have mentioned. `Parallelism` is no magic pill for poor `algorithm` and `data structure` choice.

Currently for every comparison it goes for `linear search O(N)`, thus making it `M*O(N)` for M operations, even if we make these operations `O(logN)`, even better `O(1)`, there would be a drastic improvement in the execution time.

Instead of taking `Distinct` and then searching in the `Parallel loop` using `Where` clause, use `GroupBy` to `aggregate / group` the records, and create a Dictionary in the same operation, which would ensure the easy search of records with a given name

```
var nameGroupList = Group_1.GroupBy(p => p.first_Name).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p);
```

This will help you get rid of following two operations in the original code (one of them in Parallel is a repetitive operation, which hurts the performance big time)

```
List<string> distinct_Group_1_Name = Group_1.Select(p => p.first_Name).Distinct().ToList();

List<Person> first_Name_List_1 = Group_1.Where(m => m.first_Name == distinct_Group_1_Name[dI]).ToList();
```

The `Dictionary` will be of type `Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<Person>>`, thus you get the List of Person by name in `O(1)` time and there's no repetitive search. Another issue of the code that this would handle is recreation of list and as it searches through the original list / data.

Next part that needs to be handled, which is hurting the performance is the code like this

```
p.birthday.In(merged_Dates)
```

since in the extension methods you run the `list.Contains`, as an `O(N)` operation every time, which kills the performance. Following are the possible options:

Take the following operation too out of the Parallel loop:

```
DateTime[] merged_Dates = first_Name_List_1.Join(Group_2, d => d.birthday, b => b.birthday, (d, b) => b.birthday).ToArray();
```

Instead create another `Dictionary` of type `Dictionary<string, Hashset<DateTime>>`, by intersecting the data from `Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<Person>>` created earlier, using a Data from `Group2`, you can use the appropriate `IEqualityComparer` for DateTime and thus a ready reckoner for Date list / array would be available and needn't be created everytime:

```
personDictionary["PersonCode"].Intersect(Group2,IEqualityComparer(using Date))
```

For the final result please notice, you shall store the result as `HashSet` instead of `List`. The benefit would be the `Contains` would be `O(log(N))` operation instead of `O(N)`, thus making it much faster. In fact it is also fine to have the structure like `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime,DateTime>>`, which will make it `O(1)` operation.

Try these points and suggest if there's any improvement in the working of the code.

Comment: Thanks, Mrinal! That is REALLY informative stuff and much appreciated by my soft (but hungry) brain.

Comment: Thanks, Mrinal! That is REALLY informative stuff/much appreciated by my soft (but hungry) brain. As/Was at my sample size, this was processing about 104 lists/sec. I reduced the sample size (# of birthdays) substantially and pushed it to 2600 lists/sec. By using your suggestions, I was able to increase my sample size again and am now running at about 2,000 lists/sec. I had to keep merged_dates inside the loop because the dates differ from person to person, but THANK YOU for reminding me about hashsets. How many different ways there are to do the same thing!  THANK YOU!!

Comment: In reality, this prepares a list of stock price histories for Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient comparison in which List_1 consists of stock symbols in the AMEX exchange and List_2 consists of various INDEX symbols. Unfortunately, dates differ for each stock and index as they are taken offline or dropped. As PPMCC requires both data sets to be of the same length and indexed together, this date thing proved to be the most difficult of all. THANK YOU again for your time and assistance!

Comment: @Shannon Holsinger Welcome, as its clear, just right choice of Data structures makes a huge difference, its important that we make the right choice based on requirements and reduce un-required processing. Its important to break down the issue and target each component to become as efficient as possible. Glad that it helped to an extent, if possible then please accept this as an answer and Up-Vote (helps in accruing few points :))

Comment: Also please remember though many of these Data structures look similar, but Microsoft never reinvents the wheel, all are there as they suit a specific requirement / use case

Comment: I am not aware of your exact implementation and requirements, but to the extent possible use parallel loop for non repetitive job, create efficient data structure outside it